# ¿Cómo crear nueva columna basado en la correspondencia de valores de dos columnas de dos DataFrames?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Tengo dos `DataFrame`

```
df1= 
iden   c    A1   A2    A3    
11     1     1     1   NaN
23     2     3     3   NaN
33     3     2     2     1
25     4   NaN     1   NaN
74     1   NaN   NaN   NaN

df2= 
    iden     
    11     
    77     
    99     
    25     
    74
```

Requiero crear una nueva columna en `df1`de tal manera que si los valores de `iden` en `df2`están en `iden`de `df1` les asigne el valor 'Tipo 1', de lo contrario 'Tipo 2'.

El DataFrame resultado sería:

```
resultado= 
    iden   c    A1   A2    A3   Tipo 
    11     1     1     1   NaN  Tipo 1
    23     2     3     3   NaN  Tipo 2
    33     3     2     2     1  Tipo 2
    25     4   NaN     1   NaN  Tipo 1
    74     1   NaN   NaN   NaN  Tipo 1
```

En el momento tengo el filtro de quienes son el tipo 1:

```
filtro = df1[df1.identifica.isin(df2.identifica)]
```

Pense en usar el `apply` y el `isin` pero no se como construir la sentencia para relacionar los dos DataFrame dentro de la condición

```
df1['Tipo'] = df1['iden'].apply(lambda x: [....] )
```

Agradezco en lo que me puedan ayudar

Comment: te dejo una solución implemetando `lambda` como pensaste primeramente 
`df['foo'] = df1['iden'].apply(lambda x: 'tipo1' if x in df2['iden'].tolist() else 'tipo2')`

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma muy simple es generar una serie de lógicos en función si `iden` de `df1` está en `df2`, para verificar esto, tenemos [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
df1['Tipo'] = list("Tipo 1" if x else "Tipo 2" for x in df1.iden.isin(df2.iden))
```

Por último, en función de estos lógicos establecemos la cadena a incorporar a la columna

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta. Una pregunta por qué usa una lista?

Comment: Por que lo que está adentro de los paréntesis es una expresión generadora y lo que necesitamos en realidad son los valores que se generan, transformar la expresión en una lista, logra justamente eso. Saludos

Comment: Entiendo, le agradezco mucho